# CMD move files without knowing folder name

Tags: windows, cmd, scripting

I'm using Windows CMD via an ANT Build file to move files from a sub-folder into a parent folder that is three levels up. The structure looks like this:

```
containingFolder
-tempFolder
 -unkownNamedFolder
  -contents.xyz
```

Using linux I can do this with the command `mv */*.* ..` with the current working directory being the temp folder. I don't know what the unknownNamedFolder will be called, but I do know that it will always be the only folder within the temp folder and that whatever content is within it needs to be extracted out to the containingFolder so that temp can be deleted and only the files will remain.

I've tried a command such as `/c move *\*.* .. 2>NUL` but this doesn't work.

Comment: Wildcards (`*`, `?`) can only be used in the *last* element of a path; what you could do is this: `for /D %I in ("*") do move "%~I\*.*" ".."` (double the `%`-signs in a batch file)

Comment: What is the 1) current directory, 2) directory containing the files to move, and 3) destination directory?